# Configure PhantomJS in an Ember App

Tags: javascript, ember.js, phantomjs, ember-cli, ember-testing

I'm working on an ember addon leveraging a library (PDF.js) that relies on inline styling to build DOM over a PDF rendering to enable text selection in an inline PDF viewing experience.

I can run tests in the browser and check against inline-styling just fine, however if I run them with `ember exam` or `ember test` within PhantomJS (currently headless chrome isn't supported via our tooling), the style attribute is never applied. I've verified this by printing `this.$()[0].innerHTML` from the test and seeing there's no style attribute.

I noticed that this stripping of inline styling is supported via the web security flag in PhantomJS, either through the [settings config](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) or [command line interface](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html), and is, by default, set to be enforced. Seeing as my application's CSP allows for inline styling, I want to test for my use case with similar settings.

Is there any way to supply PhantomJS a config or args through ember cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments can be set through the testem config with the [phantom_args](https://github.com/testem/testem/blob/master/docs/browser_args.md#phantomjs-args) option.

However, the issue was not due to any security settings in phantom. Setting [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) attribute directly on `this.get('element')` will not apply inline styles in phantom. You will need to reference styles directly (For example, `this.get('element').style.width = '100px';`)